# dependency conflict while installing react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using react v-18, while installing
react-virtualized it shows a error of dependency conflict, is it ok to use --force command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try npm install react-virtualized --legacy-peer-deps
or you can use --force command.
It's happening because when you are installing packages using npm, npm calculates whether there's any probability of having a conflict so if there is a chance of conflict npm doesn't allow it to be installed so these warnings are being shown and so we have to force npm to install the package.

Comment: can you explain what happen in this code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know anything in detail but when one of my friends had this problem, they tried this solution and unfortunately it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but instead of installation command I added the following line to my .npmrc file:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

For me it solved the issue.